# Pandas - Find duplicated entries in one column within rows with equal values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Assume a dataframe `df` like the following:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    A
1    b    A
2    c    A
3    c    B
4    a    B
5    b    B
6    a    C
7    a    C
8    c    C
```

I would like to find those values of `col2` where there are duplicate entries `a` in `col1`. In this example the result should be `['C]'`, since for `df['col2'] == 'C'`, `col1` has two `a` as entries.

I tried this approach

```
df[(df['col1'] == 'a') & (df['col2'].duplicated())]['col2'].to_list()
```

but this only works, if the `a` within a block of rows defined by `col2` is at the beginning or end of the block, depending on how you define the `keep` keyword of `duplicated()`. In this example, it returns `['B', 'C']`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) only for filtered rows:

```
df1 = df[df['col1'] == 'a']

out = df1.loc[df1['col2'].duplicated(keep=False), 'col2'].unique().tolist()
print (out)
['C']
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by both columns and chain wit hrows match only `a`:

```
out = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'col2'], keep=False) & 
             (df['col1'] == 'a'), 'col2'].unique().tolist()
print (out)
['C']
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generalised solution using [`Groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and [`index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
In [2632]: x = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).col2.count().to_frame()
In [2642]: res = x[x.col2 > 1].index.get_level_values(1).tolist()

In [2643]: res
Out[2643]: ['C']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group your `col1` by `col2` and count occurrences of `'a'`

```
>>> s = df.col1.groupby(df.col2).sum().str.count('a').gt(1)
>>> s[s].index.values
array(['C'], dtype=object)
```